# SQL Dynamic Optimization Tables?

Tags: sql

I am a very experienced programmer, but extremely new to SQL, which has a more limited view of things than what is available in code. I think it's possible I'm looking at this wrong in the context of SQL in general, so I'm looking for direction. I do not believe the specific SQL implementation is really important at this point. I think this is just a general SQL conceptual issue, that I'm having.

Here's what I'm thinking:

Say I am going to track the results of a very large number of sporting events (10s of millions or more), with the teams that played in them and the final scores:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
  TeamID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TeamName VCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE games (
  GameID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  TeamA INT NOT NULL,
  TeamB INT NOT NULL,
  TeamAScore INT,
  TeamBScore INT, 
  FOREIGN KEY TeamA(TeamID)
  REFERENCES teams (TeamID),
  FOREIGN KEY TeamB(TeamID)
  REFERENCES teams (TeamID)
)
```

Since the "games" table will be extremely large, when a query is made for the results of a particular team, it seems to me that searching both "TeamA" and "TeamB" columns for matches could be a very time-consuming operation. That would in turn make immediate presentation on a UI a problem.

However, if there were lists of games played by each team, the query could be made much faster (at the expense of more storage):

```
CREATE TABLE team_TeamID_games (
  GameID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY GameID(GameID)
)
```

Then displaying the list of results for a team just involves using the "team_TeamID_games" table and pulling out the results of the "games" table directly, rather than searching it.

The questionable part here starts with the idea of introducing a new table for each team.  The "TeamID" portion of the "team_TeamID_games" above would be replaced with the team ID, so there might be tables called "team_1_games", "team_2_games", etc.

That alone seems to break with what I've seen in researching SQL use.

Additionally, from what I've learned of SQL so far, there isn't really a standard way to actually link the "team_TeamID_games" table to the "TeamID" row of the "teams" table, since foreign keys reference a row, not an entire table. And that means the database doesn't really know about the connection.

Alternatively, a VARCHAR() string with the name of the other table could be stored in the "teams" table, but I don't believe that actually means anything to the database either.

- Is the concept of a link between tables done above and outside the database itself an extremely bad thing?
- Is the creation of such "dynamic" tables (not statically created up front, but created as teams are registered, and populated as the game results are entered) for each team a bad idea?
- Is there another way to accomplish this optimization?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and performance optimizations are very often highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I haven't chosen one, and as this is a conceptual question for someone new to SQL, I really would like to approach this on that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you consider "extremely" large. With e.g. 2500 teams, the result games table would be about 6 million rows. That is not even considered "large" nowadays. With 5000 teams, the games table would have 25 million rows. Still not "extremely" large nowadays.

---

The query "find all games of a specific team" can be answered using the following query:

```
select *
from games
where teama = 42
   or teamb = 42;
```

This can (usually) be improved by creating an index on each column:

```
create index idx_team_a on games (teama);
create index idx_team_a on games (teamb);
```

Postgres (and probably other DBMS products as well) would be able to use both indexes for that query. On my laptop (with 2500 teams and 6.2 million games) that query takes about [3 milliseconds](https://explain.depesz.com/s/XFFq).

Another option would be to create an index on an expression that covers both team IDs

```
create index on games ( (least(teama, teamb)) );
```

That expression can then be used to find all games for one team:

```
select *
from games
where least(teama, teamb) = 1234;
```

As only a single index is involved this [a bit faster](https://explain.depesz.com/s/PhjL): about 2 milliseconds on my laptop.

---

With 25 million rows (5000 teams), the difference between the two approaches is a bit bigger. The `OR` query takes around 15-20 milliseconds, the expression based query takes around 5-10 milliseconds.

Even 20 milliseconds doesn't seem something that would be a problem in the UI.

So with careful indexing I don't see why you would need any additional table.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure how you determined either of the values you mention for teams or games, but those are very much in the ballpark. Also, you seem to have simulated this extremely quickly. Is there a trick to doing this, so I can convince myself that things can be so efficient? As I mentioned, SQL databases are new & this speed seems counterintuitive to me, without much work on my side.

Comment: @rtillery: well the number of games is a simple calculation. If you have 2500 teams there are 2500 * 2500 possible game combinations (assuming that "a vs. b" is a different game than "b vs. a") and that is roughly 6.2 million (note that neither 6 million nor 25 million rows qualify as "extremely large" these days)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, this won't be an all play all, but will be teams playing each other multiple times. Oddly, the numbers are very close. You responded before I could edit my previous comment: Also, you seem to have simulated this extremely quickly. Is there a trick to doing this, so I can convince myself that things can be so efficient? As I mentioned, SQL databases are new & this speed seems counterintuitive to me, without much work on my side.

Comment: @rtillery: this is the script I used: https://rextester.com/DMFM15668 (note that I only generated 100 teams with that online example due to understandable restriction of the service)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name! Sorry it took a bit to get back and mark this as the answer. I've been working through your example (did I mention I'm new to SQL? :-) ). I honestly didn't understand a few parts after much searching, so I had to use a bit different technique in some cases. On my i7 laptop, 1 million indexed rows takes 2 ms, as you say. Oh also, I don't think the least() formula works for this (no guarantee the target team id would be lower than the opponent), but the OR is fine.